# How to calculate the probability of at least one "yarborough"

Tags: probability, card-games

Could I please ask for help with the following:

In a card game for four players, a pack of fifty-two cards is dealt round so that each player receives thirteen cards. A hand that contains no card greater than nine is called a yarborough. How many deals are necessary for the probability of at least one hand to be a yarborough to be greater than 1/2 (Ace ranks high).

The answer given in the book is 1267

Here's my initial reasoning:

If only one hand of 13 cards was being dealt from the pack, then the probability of a yarborough could be calculated as follows:

The sample space has 52 * 51 * … * 40 equally likely outcomes.

The number of cards having a values 9 or lower (remember ace ranks high) is 8 * 4 = 32 and so there are 32 * 31 * … * 20 outcomes for which there is no card higher than a nine among the thirteen cards dealt.

Thus, the probability of a yarborough is (32 * 31 * … * 20) / ( 52 * 51 * … * 40 ) = 0.00054703

Ok, so a yarborough is very unlikely.

So the probability in the above scenario of NOT getting a yarborough is 1 - 0.00054703 = 0.99945297

(I feel happy with the above, but from here on in I'm not so happy with my reasoning):

But in one "deal", four hands are dealt.

So could I say that the probability that every one of the four players does NOT have a yarborough is  0.99945297^4 ? This feels wrong to me as the above argument was for one hand being dealt, and probabilities on subsequent hands are affected by the result of previous hands.

Well, if I could say this then the probability that at least one yarborough is dealt would be 1 - 0.99945297^4 = 0.002186325. So very unlikely that at least one yarborough is dealt.

Then to find the number of "deals" required for the probability of at least one yarborough being dealt to be equal to 0.5 I would have to solve:

(0.99945297^4)^n = 0.5 giving n = 316.691 and so n = 317 deals.

Which is not the given answer. As I say, I feel my reasoning is faulty. Could any one please offer a correct method?

Comment: $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ is true for independent events $A$ and $B$ only.  It is invalid and incorrect to multiply probabilities of events when they are not independent.  As such your $0.99945297^4$ is indeed incorrect.  For a correct approach, consider inclusion-exclusion $\Pr(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)+\Pr(C)+\Pr(D)-\Pr(A\cap B)-\Pr(A\cap C)-\dots - \Pr(C\cap D)+\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)+\dots + \Pr(B\cap C\cap D)-\Pr(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)$

Comment: With $A$ the event that the first player received a "yarborough", $B$ the event that the second player did, etc... you should be able to calculate $\Pr(A\cap B)$ relatively easily in much the same way you found $\Pr(A)$ above.  You should also be able to convince yourself with hardly any calculation that three or more players can not simultaneously receive yarboroughs.  Symmetry helps make the calculation above much less tedious as well, leading to a quick and tidy answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Anderson-Pelham,_2nd_Earl_of_Yarborough

Comment: @JMoravitz Per the last section of my answer, it depends on how you define the term *tidy*.

Comment: @WillJagy Unless my analysis is faulty, the problem is more complicated than the corresponding wikipedia article.  The article specifies the probability of one person receiving a yarborough.  However, if you attack the problem combinatorically, this computation must be coupled with the number of ways that the remaining $(39)$ cards can be distributed to the other $3$ players.  See my answer's computation of $T_1$ and $T_2$.  I am commenting here, in case I have made an analytical flaw.

Comment: @user2661923  don't worry about it. I played bridge in high school sometimes, people used the term yarborough, and I never knew how that (or plenty of other terms)  got started; so I looked it up upon openeing this question.

Comment: As it turns out, your answer is only moderately inaccurate.  Your approach has some analytical flaws that become negligible because the probability of one person getting a yarborough is so small.  See my answer, and the subsequent comments.  It seems fairly clear that the book confused one specific person getting a yarborough with any of the $4$ players getting a yarborough.  Not surprising that the book author didn't want to *get dirty*.  The exact computation is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you have faithfully presented the problem specified by the problem composer?  Is it possible that the problem composer was instead asking how many deals are necessary until the probability is greater than $(1/2)$ that one specific person (e.g. the eldest person there, or the tallest person there) gets a yarborough?  If that is the question that the problem composer specified then the answer of $(1267)$ is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a computation of the probability by inclusion-exclusion.

The probability that some player has a Yarborough (deliberately over-counting the cases where more than one player has a Yarborough--we will compensate later) is
$$\binom{4}{1} \frac{\binom{32}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$
The probability that two players have a Yarborough is
$$\binom{4}{2} \frac{\binom{32}{26}}{\binom{52}{26}}$$
It is not possible for three or more players to have a Yarborough.
So, by inclusion-exclusion, the probability that at least one player has a Yarborough is
$$\binom{4}{1} \frac{\binom{32}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}} - \binom{4}{2} \frac{\binom{32}{26}}{\binom{52}{26}} = \boxed{0.00218812}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ denote the probability that on one dealing of $(13)$ cards to $(4)$ players, none of the $(4)$ players has a yarborough.  This implies that $0 < A < 1$.  This implies that $\ln(A) < 0.$

Then, the probability of no yarborough to anyone, in the first $n$ deals is $A^n$.

So, once $A$ is calculated, you will be looking for the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $A^n < \dfrac{1}{2}$.

This is equivalent to solving for $n$ such that

$\displaystyle e^{n \times \ln(A)} < e^{-\ln(2)}.$

Therefore, keeping in mind that $n \times \ln(A)$ will be a negative number, as will $-\ln(2)$,

you want $~~~n \ln(A) < -\ln(2) \implies n > \dfrac{-\ln(2)}{\ln(A)}.$

So, you want $n$ to be the smallest positive integer that is greater than $\dfrac{-\ln(2)}{\ln(A)}.$

Therefore, the problem has been reduced to computing $A$.

---

Unfortunately, the computation of $A$ is a job for Inclusion-Exclusion.

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Let $B = 1 - A$.

So, $B$ represents the probability that on a single deal, **at least** one of the $4$ players was dealt a yarborough.

I am going to compute $B$ combinatorically, as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

Here, $~\displaystyle D = \binom{52}{13} \times \binom{39}{13} \times \binom{26}{13} \times \binom{13}{13}.$

So, $~\displaystyle D = \frac{(52)!}{[(13)!]^4}.$

Therefore, the problem has been reduced to computing $N$.

---

Using the syntax in the Inclusion-Exclusion answer that I linked to:

For any set $E$ with a finite number of elements, let $|E|$ denote the number of elements in the set $E$.

Let $S$ denote the set of all possible ways of distributing $(13)$ card each to $(4)$ players.  That is, $|S| = D.$

Let $S_k$ denote the subset of $S$ that has player $k$ receiving a yarborough.  Here $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, since there are $4$ players.

Then, $N = |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4|$.

Let $T_1 = |S_1| + |S_2| + |S_3| + |S_4|.$

Let $T_2 = |S_1 \cap S_2| + |S_1 \cap S_3| + |S_1 \cap S_4|$ 
$+ |S_2 \cap S_3| + |S_2 \cap S_4| + |S_3 \cap S_4|$.

Let $T_3 = |S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3| + |S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_4|$ 
$+ |S_1 \cap S_3 \cap S_4| + |S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4|$.

Let $T_4 = |S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3\cap S_4|$.

Then, in accordance with Inclusion-Exclusion, you have that

$\displaystyle N = |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4| = T_1 - T_2 + T_3 - T_4.$

Therefore, the problem has been reduced to the computation of $T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4$.

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_1}$ 
The number of elements in the set $S_1$ equals the number of ways of Player-1 receiving no card higher than a $9$, while the other $(3)$ players can **then** receive any of the remaining $(39)$ cards.  This means that Player-1 received $(13)$ cards from the **reduced deck** of $(32)$ cards, since it is presumed that Player-1 did not receive any of the $(20)$ cards, $(10)$ or higher.

The number of such possible distributions is

$~\displaystyle |S_1| = \binom{32}{13} \times \binom{39}{13} \times \binom{26}{13} \times \binom{13}{13}$

$\displaystyle =~ \frac{[(32)!] \times [(39)!]}{[(19)!] \times [(13)!]^4}.$

By symmetry, $|S_1| = |S_2| = |S_3| = |S_4|.$

Therefore,

$$T_1 = 4 \times \frac{[(32)!] \times [(39)!]}{[(19)!] \times [(13)!]^4}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_2}$

Calculating $|S_1 \cap S_2|$ is very similar to the computation of $|S_1|$ in the previous section.  That is, in order for both Player-1 and Player-2 to receive a yarborough, first Player-1 must receive a yarborough from the reduced deck of $32$ cards.  Then, there will be $(32 - 13) = 19$ cards left in the reduced deck, from which Player-2 receives his cards.  Then, Player-3 and Player-4 can each receive any of the $(13)$ cards left from the $(26)$ cards in the deck.

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle |S_1 \cap S_2| = 
\binom{32}{13} \times \binom{19}{13} \times \binom{26}{13} \times \binom{13}{13}$

$\displaystyle =~ \frac{[(32)!] \times [(26)!]}{[(6)!] \times [(13)!]^4}.$

Again, by symmetry,

$$T_2 = 6 \times \frac{[(32)!] \times [(26)!]}{[(6)!] \times [(13)!]^4}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_3}$ 
Finally, I come to the easy part.
In order for players $1,2,$ and $3$ to each receive a yarborough, they would each have to receive $13$ cards from the reduced deck of $32$ cards.

This is impossible, since $(3 \times 13) > 32.$

Therefore, $|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3| = 0.$

Similarly, by symmetry,

$$T_3 = 0.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_4}$ 
The same analysis of the previous section applies here.

$$ T_4 = 0.$$

---

Final Computation(s)

$$T_1 = 4 \times \frac{[(32)!] \times [(39)!]}{[(19)!] \times [(13)!]^4}.$$

$$T_2 = 6 \times \frac{[(32)!] \times [(26)!]}{[(6)!] \times [(13)!]^4}.$$

$$N = T_1 - T_2.$$

$$D = \frac{(52)!}{[(13)!]^4}.$$

$$B = \frac{N}{D}.$$

$$A = 1 - B.$$

$$n = ~\text{the smallest positive integer}~ > 
\frac{-\ln(2)}{-\ln(A)}.$$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment of Michael Seifert, which follows this answer.

I agree.  In fact, approximating $N$ by $T_1$ greatly simplifies the computations and analysis, since it allows you to avoid any consideration of Inclusion-Exclusion.

Also, with $N$ approximated by $T_1$, the computation of $~\displaystyle B = \frac{N}{D}$ becomes much simpler.

Comment: Note that $T_2/T_1 = 1/199578$, which means that to a pretty good approximation $B \approx T_1/D$.  In other words, the chance of two players being dealt a "yarborough" is very very small compared to the chance of only one player being dealt one, which addresses the concern that the OP had about how multiple hands are being dealt out with each deal.

Comment: Very good point.  I will add an Addendum that discusses the option of bypassing Inclusion-Exclusion, and simply assuming that $N \approx T1.$

Comment: What numeric values do you get for $B,$ $A,$ and $n$? I get approximately $0.99781188,$ approximately $0.00218812,$ and $317.$ It seems to me OP's method is only slightly inaccurate and the book is wrong.

Comment: @DavidK It seems reasonable to use the approximation discussed in the Addendum.  So, $$B = \frac{N}{D} \approx \frac{4 \times [(32)!] \times [(39)!]}{[(19!)] \times [(52)!]} \approx 0.002188133$$ $$\implies A \approx 0.997811 \implies n \approx 316.428.$$  Explanation seems to be that the book answer omitted the factor of $(4)$ from the $T_1 \approx N$ computation.  This explains the discrepancy.  That is, the book answer confused one specific person getting a yarborough with any of the $4$ people getting a yarborough.

Comment: @DavidK For what it's worth, I went ahead and calculated $N$ (on my handheld calculator) as $T_1 - T_2$.  There was no appreciable difference in the computations, and $n$ still computes to $316+$.

Comment: I think you have identified why the book's answer was different. I suppose it is possible that it was the intended answer, but if so, the question was very poorly worded.

Comment: @DavidK You are assuming that the OP faithfully presented the problem, rather than misinterpreting it.

Comment: That also is a possibility! I had assumed (possibly incorrectly!) that the question was quoted verbatim.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for all of your answers, I very much appreciate your time and effort. Also, I can assure you that the problem is quoted verbatim.